# Problema com o pacote Requests

Tags: python

Estou começando com o Debian 8 e estou tentando rodar um código em Python, porém, sempre aparece o erro:

> No module named request.

Já verifiquei várias formas pra tentar corrigir, usando o pip install ...

O pacote requests está instalado

Mas o erro continua...O código é esse:

```
*from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import requests
from urllib2.request import urlopen
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
url = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=PETR4.SA&amp;d=9&amp;e=17&amp;f=2015&amp;g=d&amp;a=0&amp;b=3&amp;c=2000&amp;ignore=.csv'
petr_csv = urlopen(url)
data_petr = np.genfromtxt(petr_csv, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
# Dando uma olhada no cabecalho dos dados.
data_petr[0:4, 0:]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se o pacote está mesmo instalado:

```
> pip show requests

Name: requests
Version: 2.16.4
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: http://python-requests.org
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages
Requires: certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna
```

Seu código funcionou aqui.